# Apache Maven Download using CURL is timed out

Tags: maven, docker, curl, download

```
curl -O "https://www.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz"
```

This is the command I am using from terminal to download maven but it's either timed out or `curl: (7) Failed to connect to www.apache.org port 443: Operation timed out.`

If I use browser to download, no issue.

My assumption is the ssl connection or certificate issue. Any idea how can I resolve the curl issue.

Please take note, I am using this in a Dockerfile to create docker image and here is that:

```
FROM ******/mule-42x:v2.2.1

ENV MAVEN_VERSION 3.6.3

RUN mkdir -p /opt/maven \
  && cd /opt/maven \
  && curl -O "https://www.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/${MAVEN_VERSION}/binaries/apache-maven-${MAVEN_VERSION}-bin.tar.gz" \
  && tar xzvf "apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz" \
  && rm "apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION-bin.tar.gz"

ENV MAVEN_HOME "/opt/maven/apache-maven-$MAVEN_VERSION"

ENV PATH=$MAVEN_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: You should download the apache maven distribution from Central repository and not from the apache distribution area for example: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.6.3/

Comment: Who not using already existing docker containers for Maven: https://hub.docker.com/_/maven

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to run the command presented in the question and encountered the following errors:

```
curl -O "https://www.apache.org/dist/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz"
```

1. curl tries to verify the SSL certificate but fails with the following message:

```
curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle"
 of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default
 bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file
 using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in
 the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a
 problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might
 not match the domain name in the URL).
If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use
 the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

So I've added `-k` flag as the message suggests.

2. Now this works, however the http call returns and HTML page with 302 (redirect) to `https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz`

So the command that has worked for me is:

```
curl -O -k https://downloads.apache.org/maven/maven-3/3.6.3/binaries/apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.tar.gz
```

**An Important side note:**

I'm assuming that you've configured the network right and it has all the proper proxy definitions if you're running behind the proxy in your organization, otherwise you should define proxy first.

All in all I suggest you running this command 'manually' first (from the command line not as a part of the build I mean) outside the docker on the machine where you run the `docker build` and only when you make sure it works run it in a docker file.

Comment: I strongly recommend not to turn of ssl certificate verification via `-k`  ...and the manual page suggested...